# Constraints in tableViewCell not showing correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, constraints

I've created  a tableView with a dynamic size height like following `130.0/320.0 * tableView.bounds.width`. In the Cell i have to properties. A `UIimageView` that shows an image and a `UIView` that shows an overlay. However the Overlay UIView isn't covering the whole image. Why is that?

**Illustration**

[image]

**UiView Contraints**

[image]

**View Frames**

[image]

Comment: give equal width and height constraint to overlay view

Comment: Xcode => Debug => View Debugging => Show View Frames => ScreenShot => Post

Comment: ViewFrames has been added and the small margin above is from another cell

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: No i can't seem to fix. it seem to work fine when the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` correspond to the height in the interface Builder. However since i have a dynamic height it doesnt.

Comment: Remove View's constraint to SuperView, just keep all four spaces to ImageView and equal width and equal height to imageView.

Comment: And is there are only two views inside your tableView cell that is imageView and UIView?

Comment: No there is a couple of labels, but have not added these yet.

Comment: Could it fix it to create a xib instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106364/discussion-between-bharat-modi-and-peter-pik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the constraint as i have set to reproduce the scenario as you have,

**ImageView Constraints:**

[image]

Increase the imageView height 2pts more than the cell height. (It seems your image is slightly transparent at the bottom)

**OverlayView:**

[image]

**View Hierarchy:**

[image]

And the result is,

[image]